# How to find a initial condition such that the solution of a second ordered ODE is bounded?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Let $A=\pmatrix{1&2\\1&1}$. The ODE is $X''= AX$. How to find an initial condition such that the solution of this second ordered differential equation is bounded?

Comment: So your system is $X''=\pmatrix{1&2\\1&1}X$? Or is the matrix symmetric?

Comment: @LutzL You are right

Comment: Did you try solving it? Maybe using a computer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The matrix has eigenvalues $1\pm\sqrt2$, one positive, one negative. The solutions on the positive eigenspace have terms $e^{\pm\sqrt{1+\sqrt2}t}$, the other $\sin(\sqrt{\sqrt2-1}t)$ and $\cos(\sqrt{\sqrt2-1}t)$. Depending on whether you want the solution bounded for $t>0$ or for all $t\in\Bbb R$, you have 3 or 2 bounded components and need to chose the initial values so that they avoid the eigen-spaces of the other 1 or 2 components.

---

If only the trigonometric components are admissible, then the bounded solutions have
$$
x_1=c_1\cos(\sqrt{\sqrt2-1}t)+c_2\sin(\sqrt{\sqrt2-1}t)
$$
and from reading the first line of the system one also gets
$$
x_2=\frac{x_1''-x_1}2=-c_1\frac{\sqrt2}2\cos(\sqrt{\sqrt2-1}t) - c_2\frac{\sqrt2}2\sin(\sqrt{\sqrt2-1}t)
$$
from which one can read the space of admissible initial values $X(0), X'(0)$.

Comment: Should the solutions be $e^{(1\pm\sqrt2) t}$

Comment: You are solving $x''-(1\pm\sqrt2)x=0$, thus you get a further square root in the exponential factors resp. frequencies.